# how to use split and substring and foreach to handle array

Tags: powershell

how to use split and substring and foreach to output below information. thanks.

I have tried with split and substring and variables to handle one row. how to use foreach handle 3 or more row.  thanks.

input:

[array]

server1 OS version 2012

server2 OS version 2012

server3 OS version 2012

Expected output:

server1 2012

server2 2012

server3 2012

Comment: Sorry, but you need to format your question better and explain your issue better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example of your array is a bit ambiguous as I'm not sure exactly how it's structured.  Assuming each record is just a string as you defined in your question, the code below may work for you.

I split each element using "space" as a delimiter.  I select the first and last element and I then join the elements back together to produce the string shown in your expected output.

```
$ary = @(
    'server1 OS version 2012',
    'server2 OS version 2012',
    'server3 OS version 2012'
)

foreach($item in ($ary | Select-Object -Skip 1) ) {
    ($item.Split(" ") | Select-Object -Index 0, 3) -join " "
}
```

Comment: No problem, happy to help!  If it solved your question, could you please mark as the answer? :)

Comment: Hi Steven,  sorry i have another question , How do I start with the second row?   such as in put has 3 row (server 1  2012,server 2  2012 ,server 3 2012).   but out put only need second row and third row(server 2  2012 , server 3 2012)?

Comment: No problem, I just updated my answer.  You use `Select-Object` on the array and use the `-Skip 1` to skip the first line.  I also fixed an error where `-Index` was `1, 3` instead of `0, 3` which is what it should've been.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = @( 'server1 OS version 2012', 'server2 OS version 2012', 'server3 OS version 2012' )

$array | % { $token = @($_ -split ' '); "$($token[0]) $($token[3])" }
```